# Position:sticky element which is nested into another sticky element doesn't work in Edge

Tags: html, css, css-position, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to develop table with fixed header and fixed sevelar columns.
I use `position: sticky` for this and it works well in Chrome/Safari/Firefox, but I found issue in Microsoft Edge.

If you create element with `position:sticky; top: 0;` and insert other element with `position: sticky; left: 0;`, Edge ignores nested element.

Open this example **in Edge** and check this: https://codepen.io/finethanks/pen/aRWByx

Is it a bug of Edge?

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.content {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
}

.sticky-wrapper {
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background: yellow;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="sticky-wrapper">
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

"sticky" value not supported in Edge version less than 16.

Please see the browser compatibility of position css property on this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Browser_compatibility

Comment: I agree with the suggestion given by the Abdellatif. I make a test with your sample code in MS Edge and other browsers. I am using Edge 17 and it is working fine for me. If you are using older version then try to install the latest update and make a test with it. If issue persist then let us know about that. We will try to provide further suggestion to you.